# Null on EntityType Field when submit Form Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a problem in Symfony with the form systeme.

I have two entities : Annonce and Ville.

One Ville can have many annonce, so here are the entity declarations :

Annonce :

```
**

class Annonce
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         *
         */
        private $id;
       /**
       * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ville",cascade={"persist"})
       * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ville_id", referencedColumnName="id")
       */
       private $ville;
```

**

and Ville:

```
class Ville
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ville;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Adresse", mappedBy="ville")
     */
```

I create also a FormType for Annonce like this :

```
class AnnonceType extends AbstractType
{


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('voiture', VoitureType::class)
        ->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'       => 'AppBundle:Ville',
                'placeholder' => ''
            ))
        ->add('prixJour', IntegerType::class, array(
          'label'=>'Cmimi ditor i qerase'
        ))
        ->add('exigences', TextareaType::class, array(
          'label'=>'Eksigjenca te tjera'
        ))
        /*
        ->add('photos', FileType::class, array(
          'required'=>false,
          'multiple'=>true
        ))*/
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
          'label' => 'Ruaj annoncen tende'
        ));
        /*
        $builder->get('photos')
            ->addModelTransformer(new FilesToPhotosTransformer());**/
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Annonce'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'appbundle_annonce';
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $annonce = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Annonce')->find($id);
            $form   = $this->createForm(AnnonceType::class, $annonce);
            if (null === $annonce) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException("L'annonce d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
            }
if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
                $session = $request->getSession();
                $tabPhotos = $session->get('photos');

                if ($tabPhotos) {
                    foreach ($tabPhotos as $ph) {
                        $photo =  $this->getDoctrine()
                      ->getRepository('AppBundle:Photo')
                      ->find($ph);
                        $annonce->addPhoto($photo);
                    };
                };
                $em->flush();
                $session->remove('photos');
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('profile');
            }
return $this->render('corent/edit_vehicle.html.twig', array('form'=>$form->createView(),"photos"=>$arrayPhoto,"annonceID"=>$annonce->getID()));
    }
```

When i render the view from the controller, the Ville field is correct, i have all the villes listed.
But when i submit the form, the ville submited data is always null and i can't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: I feel like we are missing the most important piece of the puzzle, your controller code where things like that are actually handled.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i updated the post with the controller

Comment: have you any solution?